# Why when I create an class can't find-symbol it?

Tags: common-lisp, symbols

I'm confuse about the symbols now, I tried:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defclass foo2 () ())
#<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::FOO2>
CL-USER> (describe 'foo2)
COMMON-LISP-USER::FOO2
  [symbol]

FOO2 names the standard-class #<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::FOO2>:
  Direct superclasses: STANDARD-OBJECT
  No subclasses.
  Not yet finalized.
  No direct slots.
; No value
CL-USER> (find-symbol "foo2")
NIL
NIL
```

Why I can't found the "foo2" symbol with the `find-symbol` function?

What I want do with this:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defun my-make-instance (name n) (make-instance (make-symbol (format nil "~a-~a" name n)))
MY-MAKE-INSTANCE
CL-USER> (my-make-instance "foo" 2)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-PCL:CLASS-NOT-FOUND-ERROR foo2 {1003A3A003}>.
```

And I get:

```
 There is no class named #:|foo2|.
```

how to I do this?

And other case:

```lisp
CL-USER> (describe 'foo2)
COMMON-LISP-USER::FOO2
  [symbol]

FOO2 names the standard-class #<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::FOO2>:
  Direct superclasses: STANDARD-OBJECT
  No subclasses.
  Not yet finalized.
  No direct slots.
; No value
CL-USER> (describe (intern "foo2"))
COMMON-LISP-USER::|foo2|
  [symbol]
; No value
```

Why it happened? Is the "foo2" create by defclass a internal symbol, isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Common Lisp is case sensitive and the reader is case converting; your source code generally gets converted to upper case when it is read by the compiler / interpreter. The symbol named "foo2" does not exist in your example, but the symbol named "FOO2" does.
- The call to `make-symbol` will return a new symbol object, not the symbol object associated with your class.

The easiest way to fix your code would be to replace your `make-symbol` call in `my-make-instance` with a call to `read-from-string` to get the same case converting reader behavior to be used on your argument string. The reader will then also intern the symbol in the current package, ensuring it is the same symbol object as the one associated with your class. You also probably want to use `defun` instead of `defmacro` to define `my-make-instance` in this case.
In short you probably want the following code:

```
(defun my-make-instance (name n)
  (make-instance (read-from-string (format nil "~a-~a" name n))))
(defclass foo-2 () ())
(my-make-instance "foo" 2)
;returns below instance
#<FOO-2 {100AB67443}>
```

Comment: Thanks, Also It solve with `(intern (string-upcase name))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you describe the symbol and get

> `FOO2` names the standard-class `#<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::FOO2>`:

then `FOO2` in uppercase characters really indicates that the symbol has an uppercase name.

```
* 'foo2
FOO2
```

Now you can use the function `symbol-name` to get the name of a symbol as a string:

```
* (symbol-name 'foo2)
"FOO2"
```

As you can see above, the name is uppercase.

Using the uppercase name to find the symbol then works:

```
* (find-symbol "FOO2")
FOO2
:INTERNAL
```